# Cloudflare Page Speed HTTP Headers

Tags: cloudflare

I've set Cloudflare up and it's working great, the only problem I have is that this keeps coming up in page speed insights

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

I've set the cache at Cloudflare to be 4 days and PageSpeed is picking up on this, is there a bit of code I'm missing here?

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vouchertoday.uk

Comment: Please post the URL that we can test. Also post the URLs of the resources this warning is showing for. Some cannot be avoided.

Comment: https://www.vouchertoday.uk